# echo/printf vs. ending php brackets?

Tags: php

Very simple question, requiring a very simple answer.

If I've got some PHP files that need to output a decent amount of html with variables, is it considering better to use echo/printf or is it better to end the php and start it up again?

ex:

```
<?php
$varA = 'foo';
$varB = 'bar';
?>
<span><?php echo $foo; ?></span>
<div><?php echo 'content ' . $bar; ?></div>
<?php
//continue php here
?>
```

is that considered better than

```
<?php
$varA = 'foo';
$varB = 'bar';
printf('<span> . $foo . </span>');
printf('<div>content ' . $bar . '</div>');
//continue php here
?>
```

or is the latter considered "better", OR is one even considered better than the other, period!?

Thanks!

Comment: Thats all about how you like your code to look. There is no right or better way. If you echo just the content or also the HTML tags does not matter really. Do it as you like.

Comment: Alright, that clears up alot :). I see lots of people complain about how php files look/function, so I wasn't sure if there was a "considered best practice". thanks! :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - is there a reason to use echo, or is it just your personal preference?

Comment: personal preference, it completely depends on you as @Nitram said, you can do `<div><?php echo 'content ' . $bar; ?></div>` like `<?php echo "<div>content".$bar."</div>"; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is fairly subjective, so my *opinion* is that the first approach is cleaner and easier to read, due mainly to the fact that if you happen to be working with a team who's attempting to exercise some separation of concerns, then the front-end developer will have an easier time spotting the HTML tags if they themselves are not `echo`'d out by PHP (They may not even *know* PHP).  Most text editors will not provide the pretty syntax highlighting for the HTML if it is wrapped in a PHP string.

It might also be noted that if you are working in a strict MVC environment, then your views should contain as little PHP as possible, and should really just be a bunch of `echo`s.  I think the first approach lends itself towards providing a more HTML look and feel, if you will.

As @hyphen-this has stated, heredoc syntax is also an accepted route, and removes the need for jumping in and out of PHP mode.

Answer (score 3):

echo/printf are both the same thing, it is personal preference. But you may want to consider using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). IMHO is is easier to read than peppering html with php tags and echo statements.

```
echo <<<HTML
    <h1>$foo</h1>
    <p>$bar</p>
    <span>$fizz</span>
HTML;
```

Comment: I was unaware of the heredoc syntax. It looks like it might actually be a great fit for my application!

Comment: A quick heads-up, heredocs don't work when calling functions or when calling methods on objects  (i.e. $myobj->foo() wont work in a  heredoc)

Comment: Is there a way to "escape" the heredoc for something like that?

Comment: Another question... if I need to do `<div style="width: $var px">` - how do I NOT have a space between the variable and the px?

Comment: Actually, it seems like heredoc might not be what I need :/. It doesn't quite allow me to do what I need to do. I appreciate it though, and will use it for some simpler outputs

Comment: To avoid spaces simple wrap the variable in curly braces. But there is no way to escape methods, you can still access object properties like $obj->foo, but escaping with curly braces won't work like it does in strings (i.e "{$obj->do()}").